# want to know in broad the usage of indices in Python

Tags: python

i am new in python,

my question is that ,why we use indices [1:-1] while want get output of any string such as

```
 v= ['Name','Position','Join_date']
 print (str(v)[1:-1])
```

i notice that if i don't use the indices then there is no output is showing.why?

please help me and it will be great  if you give me a tutorial link about the usage of indices in Python.

Thank You.

Comment: You mean `print (str(v))` has no output?

Comment: The Python tutorial first introduces indexing in its section on strings: http://docs.python.org/2/tutorial/introduction.html#strings and continues in its section on lists: http://docs.python.org/2/tutorial/introduction.html#lists

Answer (score 1):

`[1:-1]` are used to remove the beginning `[` and closing `]` of the output of str(v)

```
>>> v= ['Name','Position','Join_date']
>>> print(str(v))
['Name', 'Position', 'Join_date']
>>> print(str(v)[1:-1])
'Name', 'Position', 'Join_date'
```